# Check when i close kendoWindow by Click on the Button close

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a kendo window, and I need to pick up when I click on the close button in the kendo window, but I can not pick up the event.

I have to do it in a special way, I explain.

I have a kendo window, which contains an iframe, and this iframe is changing according to some parameters. What I need is to create a confirm when a certain iframe is loaded (This last one is done), I just need to be able to pick up when I click on the close button in the kendo window.

Add a code example:

```
 if (!ventanaNombrePantalla.data("kendoWindow")) {
    ventanaNombrePantalla.kendoWindow({
        width: "300px",
        height: "117px",
        title: "Tittle",
        visible: false,
        modal: true,
        actions: ["Maximize", "Close"],
        resizable: false,
        // <%'Descripción: función que se ejecuta cuando se cierra la ventanaNombrePantalla para ocultar el div pantallaJV
        // 'Inputs:
        // 'Outputs:
        // 'DFPJSCADA0700
        // %>
        close: function (e) {
            //if ($("#ventanaNuevaPantalla").)
            $("#divPantallaJV").hide();
            dialogoAbierto = false;
            var url = $("#ventanaNuevaPantalla").attr('src').split("/")[3];//That is a iframe inside the window.

            if(url == "modalBlockLy.asp"){
                e.preventDefault();
                //Here is where i have the problem. I only want this, when the user do click on close.
                //I close the window, with two ways, with the button [X]
                //and invoing ventanaNombrePantalla.close()

            }

            $("#ventanaNuevaPantalla").attr("src", "");

            //this.content($("#body").hide());
        },
        open: function () {
            //this.content($("#body").show());
        }
    }).data("kendoWindow").center();
}
```

Another way:

```
$(ventanaNombrePantalla.element).closest('.k-window').find('.k-icon.k-i-close').on("click", function (e) {
    //Here, ventanaNombrePantalla.element is null...
    //debugger;
    e.stopPropagation(); // In case you want to 'prevent' the window closing
});
```

Comment: You mean [this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYspf.png) or an specific button inside the window's body ?

Comment: Yes, that button. I tried with that code  `$(document).on("click", "span.k-icon.k-i-close", function (ex) {//Code for prevent button click})`, but seems does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! with that code:

```
$(ventanaNombrePantalla).closest('.k-window').find('.k-icon.k-i-close').closest('a').on("click", function (e) {
        if(!confirm("¿Desea cerrar la ventana?")){
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Now, i have another question. Now, i get two confirm, one behind other. Why?. (Edit). I get many confirm as many times I open the modal

Comment: Solved, I have placed that code inside a .load of an iframe. so every time it was loaded, the onclick was reloaded

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the window events?

```
.Events(events => events.Close("myCloseEvent"))
```

https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/window/events

Comment: This is for MVC Kendo, I need the jQuery Version. With the event close i have also tried

Comment: Yes, I tried @GeorgeB, but, my cassuistic only must run when the user close the Window when click on the button close.

Comment: Could you provide some code for the window and the events surrounding it? This would help a lot.

Comment: Does it work differently if you link to a function instead or using the inline one on close?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: I tried to bind directly the class span.k-icon.k-i-close with a click, but what happens is that the close of the kendo function is executed first before it is

Comment: So instead of: close: function (e) { yourCode } have you tried: close: functionName. And then have your function inside of a related JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Well I could achieve that with this selector:

```
$(wnd.element).closest('.k-window').find('.k-header .k-window-actions a.k-button').on("click", function(e) {
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/@marcio/aSiFoYuB)

Check it out if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution. But, when i try to show wnd.element, it appears as undefined variable. I don't Know why. I am working in Kendo UI V2013.1.319. Can be my version wrong?

Comment: @PedroJose you need to set **your** variable name there, `wnd` was just an example.. try something like `$(ventanaNombrePantalla.element)`.

Comment: Of course I have done it with my variable, but it still returns undefined

Comment: @PedroJose well, there is something wrong with you variable then, like scope or something else. You can see in the demo I've built that it works.